# how to open lib file library in c laguage how to do this?

Tags: c, codevisionavr

i want to open "alcd.h" library (it's about working with character lcd in AVR microcontroller that it is a "C library").

how should i open this library?
i open it with txt and Codevision, but it show me wrong codes.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

On your screenshot `alcd.lib` is opened not `alcd.h`. .h files is usual text file.

Comment: tnx. i want to open lib file now.
because i havenot .h file.

Comment: @hadimargo a lib is a binary file. You can't open it as text a human can understand.